# Android sdk / Java - trim bad encoded data from string

Tags: java, android, character-encoding

how to trim unknown encoding from a string in Android/Java.

From this :    `21044564������������������������������������������������`

To this:

```
21044564
```

---

**Edit**

I am using Host Card Emulation to retrieve data from a Smart Card.
I am storing data "21044564" in Smart Card via third party software.

I retrieve data in bytes and I'm converting bytes to String via this code

```
String fileData = new String(payload, "UTF-8");
```

And output is:

```
21044564������������������������������������������������
```

Comment: Instead of giving this question a -1, if they would actually explain why this question is bad then it would actually be helpful.

Comment: I suggest that this is the wrong question.  Instead of just trimming the unknown encoding, find out where this string is coming from and why it has all these characters in it.  It could be that there's important data that you don't just want to throw out blindly.  Maybe you're passing the wrong parameters to some service, and it's returning data in the wrong encoding. The fact that you're getting this string and it seems to be unexpected is indicative of some other problem, and simply throwing away the evidence is likely to lead to more problems.  Find the root cause.

Comment: Assuming you only wont to keep alphanumeric characters in the string use a regex: `str.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");`

Comment: @ajb Thanks and I agree. I shall investigate further into this issue. Anyway I have updated the question.

Comment: @shash678 Thanks that worked for now. But what if the output is something like "hello world��". How to preserve space ?

Comment: Use `str.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", "");`

Comment: @shash678 great, that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only wont to keep alphanumeric characters and spaces in the string use a regex like so:

```
String str = "21044564������������������������������������������������";
str = str.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", "");
```